# Using host variables in a PL/pgSQL trigger functions

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql, embedded-sql

I am trying to figure out how to write a trigger function in PL/pgSQL that can select values into host variables in an Embedded SQL/C program. I am new to SQL, so I apologize if my terminology is a bit off. Basically, on a change to the table, I want the function to trigger a view in order to update the values stored in host variables.

This is the view I have created and tested to work:

```
EXEC SQL CREATE VIEW idfound AS SELECT id, num FROM newtable WHERE id = 1;
```

This is how I have called the view, using host variables dbID and dbNum:

```
EXEC SQL SELECT * INTO :dbID, :dbNum FROM idfound;
```

Here is the trigger I have created:

```
EXEC SQL CREATE idTrigger AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE ON newtable 
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE idFunc();
```

And here is the trigger function I would like to use:

```
EXEC SQL CREATE FUNCTION idFunc() RETURNS TRIGGER AS $idTrigger$
    BEGIN
    SELECT * INTO :dbID, :dbNum FROM idfound;
    END;
$idTrigger$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

For testing purposes, I am using pgAdmin III. When I change the function to perform any action that doesn't use the host variables (such as update a value in a predefined row), I can see that it is created. However, I am unable to get it to create the trigger or trigger function using the host variables.

Right now, I am just trying to figure out how to achieve this in general, so I am aware that my current code doesn't actually do much. The general idea is that I want my trigger function to call a predefined view that uses host variables in C. If there is a better way of implementing the trigger, that advice would be greatly appreciated as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trigger functions are executed in the server environment and cannot access the memory space of the client environment, neither for reading nor writing. That's a fundamental point of the client-server architecture, so there's no workaround, this is just not possible.

The closer workable equivalent may be for the trigger to [NOTIFY](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-notify.html) and for the client to [LISTEN](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-listen.html) and consume the notifications and the associated payload.

Comment: Thank you, this is all I needed to hear. I've been searching around for awhile, but I had a feeling that what I was trying to achieve was just not possible.